# The named parameter 'child' isn't defined. in Center() constructor

Tags: dart, flutter

I ran flutter upgrade today, and now I am getting an error that says-

```
[dart] The named parameter 'child' isn't defined.
```

The project is newly created and the default code is untouched, but it still has the same Error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I reinstalled the flutter SDK to solve the problem. After a few days, the same error occurred, but then I Started hovering over the red line, after a minute, the error was solved automatically. I guess the SDK connects with internet to check for all the libraries and syntax stuff once we open the IDE.

Answer (score 24):

Clean the project cache by running

```sh
flutter clean cache
```

Then invalidate caches / **restart** Android Studio or VS Code.

Comment: After, run `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 20):

Try Restarting your Analysis Dart Server.

1. At the bottom of Android Studio `click` on the `Dart Analysis` tab
2. `Click` on the Restart icon.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

In my case it happens when I name the widget with the same name of a flutter component, like so:

```dart
class OutlineButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OutlineButton(
      child: Text('+R\$ 5'),
      onPressed: () {},
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You need to change the name of the created component with a different name, for example:

```dart
class CustomOutlineButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OutlineButton(
      child: Text('+R\$ 5'),
      onPressed: () {},
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to file Settings
2. Search Flutter (in the search bar)
3. Provide Flutter SDK path

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. It looks like I changed a flutter lib file by mistake.

To fix this, without reinstalling Flutter SDK:

- go to your Flutter SDK installation path
- open terminal and type: `git status`
- it will show the modified files in red (ex: `modified:   packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart`
- revert modifications file using: `git checkout FILE_PATH` (ex: `git checkout packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart`)

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of the old cache. Just clean the cache with the following command

```
flutter clean cache
```

Comment: It's that + [restarting VSCode afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64162141/3118542) that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is -
Change the name of the class in which you are using the Center widget because, according to the standards of flutter you cannot write the name of the class same as the widget you are using inside that class. If you do so, then you cannot be able to make child or children inside that widget.

Also, the solution of Felipe Augusto is correct.