# TextButton the named parameter 'child' isn't defined

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I got errors when updating my flutter version to 3.3.8. All of textbutton class has these errors. Actually, I just need to use elevatedButton but Im curious what is the correct syntax if we want to use textbutton?

[image]

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480043/the-named-parameter-child-isnt-defined-in-center-constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
TextButton(
          onPressed: () =>handleSignUp(),
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
          ),
          child: const Text('DAFTAR'),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The style inside your `style: TextButton.styleform` needed a `ButtonStyle` as a type. you can't put a TextButton widget insedo of Textbutton too

this is a simple TextButton that you can refer

```dart
TextButton(
    child: Text('Text'),
    style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red)),
    onPressed: () {
         // action on pressed
    },
),
```