# protocol/client.dart file giving 'The named parameter 'context' isn't defined.' error

Tags: flutter, dart, serverpod

I'm using Serverpod to set up my Flutter app.

However, one of the files which I haven't touched is giving the following error:

```
The named parameter 'context' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'context'.dartundefined_named_parameter
```

The error comes from the `context: context` part from the `protocol/client.dart` file below:

```
class Client extends _i1.ServerpodClient {
  Client(
    String host, {
    _i3.SecurityContext? context,
    _i1.AuthenticationKeyManager? authenticationKeyManager,
  }) : super(
          host,
          _i4.Protocol(),
          context: context,
          authenticationKeyManager: authenticationKeyManager,
        ) {
    example = _EndpointExample(this);
  }

  late final _EndpointExample example;

  @override
  Map<String, _i1.EndpointRef> get endpointRefLookup => {'example': example};

  @override
  Map<String, _i1.ModuleEndpointCaller> get moduleLookup => {};
}
```

I have tried `flutter clean` and restarting VS code, plus [updating my flutter sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779583/6733153), however with no success.

Any idea what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a version of `serverpod_service_client` that is not compatible with the latest version of `serverpod_client` (Looks like you have `serverpod_client` updated, but `serverpod_service_client` is still on an older version).

`_i1` is an import alias for the `serverpod_client` package, and as you can see in the new constructor of `ServerpodClient`, there is no `context` parameter (most likely replaced by `securityContext`):

[serverpod_client/lib/src/serverpod_client_io.dart, line 21](https://github.com/serverpod/serverpod/blob/main/packages/serverpod_client/lib/src/serverpod_client_io.dart#L21)

```dart
ServerpodClient(
  super.host,
  super.serializationManager, {
  dynamic securityContext,
  super.authenticationKeyManager,
  super.logFailedCalls,
  super.streamingConnectionTimeout,
  super.connectionTimeout,
}) {
  // ...
```

And in the latest version of `serverpod_service_client` the constructor of `Client` class should be like this:

[serverpod_service_client/lib/src/protocol/client.dart, line 234](https://github.com/serverpod/serverpod/blob/main/packages/serverpod_service_client/lib/src/protocol/client.dart#L234)

```dart
Client(
  String host, {
  dynamic securityContext,
  _i1.AuthenticationKeyManager? authenticationKeyManager,
  Duration? streamingConnectionTimeout,
  Duration? connectionTimeout,
}) : super(
        host,
        _i14.Protocol(),
        securityContext: securityContext,
        authenticationKeyManager: authenticationKeyManager,
        streamingConnectionTimeout: streamingConnectionTimeout,
        connectionTimeout: connectionTimeout,
      ) {
  insights = EndpointInsights(this);
}
```

Which differs from the code you posted. So you can fix it by either **upgrading `serverpod_service_client`** or **downgrading `serverpod_client`** to make both packages compatible.

Comment: I performed `fluttter pub upgrade` in my `app_client` directory, and it updated both packages: `serverpod_client 1.2.1 (was 1.2.0)` & `serverpod_service_client 1.2.1 (was 1.2.0)`. However I'm still getting the same error. It didn't seem to change the file.

Comment: Are you sure the lib file that you're opening has the correct path for its version? (something like `hosted/pub.dev/serverpod_service_client-1.2.1`). Also is the main `serverpod` package upgraded too?

Comment: Yes that's correct, the path is: `Users/myname/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/serverpod_service_client-1.2.1`. No, the main serverpod package is still at `1.1.1`. I performed flutter upgrade but it did not upgrade.

Comment: `serverpod-1.1.1`  is most likely using the older `serverpod_service_client`. Can't you upgrade it manually in pubspec?

Comment: Yes you're right. I have just updated it manually to `serverpod: ^1.2.1`. Any idea where to go from here? Still getting the initial error.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's still happening, is there multiple sub-package with multiple pubspec in your project? Also you can do the cleaning again, and maybe delete pubspec.lock or something like that

Comment: I changed everything manually to `1.2.1` - and then when I ran `flutter pub get` I go this response: `Because serverpod >=1.2.1 depends on serverpod_service_client 1.2.1 which doesn't match any versions, serverpod >=1.2.1 is forbidden.`. Which doesn't make sense as 1.2.1 does exist: https://pub.dev/packages/serverpod_service_client/versions

Comment: In your pubspec.yaml, what's the environment: sdk: ?

Comment: Also have you tried `flutter upgrade -f`? @Zorgan

Comment: `environment: sdk: '>=2.19.0 <4.0.0'`...and yes, I just tried `flutter upgrade -f` and it says `Flutter is already up to date on channel stable - Flutter 3.16.8`